# register custom OID handler

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, snmp

I a struggling to make the following code to work.
I want to register a OID and wit for a GET request but the code has an error that I can't solve.

```
from pysnmp.carrier.asyncio.dgram import udp
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413 import ntfrcv
from pysnmp.smi import builder, exval, view, error
from pysnmp.proto import rfc1902
from functools import partial

# create SNMP engine instance
snmpEngine = engine.SnmpEngine()

# load custom MIB
mibBuilder = snmpEngine.getMibBuilder()
mibPath = mibBuilder.getMibSources() + (builder.DirMibSource('/home/pi/'),)
mibBuilder.setMibSources(*mibPath)
mibBuilder.loadModules('MY-MIB')

snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.mibInstrumController.mibBuilder = mibBuilder

# create UDP server transport
udpServerTransport = udp.UdpTransport().openServerMode(('0.0.0.0', 161))

def custom_oid_handler(snmp_engine, oid, tag, value):
    # Handle the request for the custom OID here
    # oid: the OID being requested
    # tag: the type of the requested OID (integer, string, etc.)
    # value: the value associated with the requested OID (if any)
    #1.3.6.1.4.1.59270.1.1
    # For example, to return a string value for the OID:
    if oid == (1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 123456, 1):
        return rfc1902.OctetString("Custom value for OID 1.3.6.1.4.1.123456.1")
    else:
        # If the OID is not recognized, return an error
        return exval.noSuchObject

# register custom OID handler
reqMsgID = snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.getNextReqMsgID()
snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.registerContextEngineId(
    snmpEngine.snmpContext,
    lambda eng, pdu, msgID=reqMsgID, cbFun=partial(custom_oid_handler, snmp_engine): (
        (msgID,), (snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.ANY_TYPE,), (snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.CONTEXT_EXACT_MATCH, 0, 0)
    )
)


# add a community string for SNMPv1
community = config.CommunityData('public')
config.addV1System(snmpEngine, 'my-area', community)

# allow read access to the entire OID tree under 1.3.6
config.addVacmUser(snmpEngine, 1, 'my-area', 'noAuthNoPriv', (1, 3, 6), (1, 3, 6))

# start the SNMP server to listen for requests
ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine).transportDispatcher.registerTransport(udpServerTransport)
ntfrcv.NotificationReceiver(snmpEngine).transportDispatcher.jobStarted(1)

print("SNMP server listening on port 161")
```

The error is:
reqMsgID = snmpEngine.msgAndPduDsp.getNextReqMsgID()
AttributeError: 'MsgAndPduDispatcher' object has no attribute 'getNextReqMsgID'

Any ideas?

Comment: First, identify the PySNMP version you are using. Its API differs significantly in different versions.

Comment: Version: 4.4.12

Comment: The official example is https://github.com/etingof/pysnmp/blob/v4.4.12/examples/v1arch/asyncore/agent/cmdrsp/implementing-scalar-mib-objects-over-ipv4-and-ipv6.py